# UIPageViewController Delegate method is called only first time

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with page curl effect. I am trying to implement two-page mode for landscape on iPad. For this, I need to use the spine location delegate method. **But the thing is this method is called only for the first time when viewcontroller opens. But for orientation changes, this method is not getting called.**

Any example or sample project that has this two-page mode implemented would be appreciated. I am unable to find any example or sample in swift

**Here is my codes:**

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationFor orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewController.SpineLocation {
        if Utils.shared.isIpad() && orientation.isLandscape {
            self.isDoubleSided = true
            self.jumpToPage(page: UserDefaults.currentPage)
            return .mid
        }
        self.isDoubleSided = false
        self.jumpToPage(page: UserDefaults.currentPage)
        return .max
    }
```

**My pager setup:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initPager()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func initPager() {
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        //        let initialPage = 0
        for index in 0...623 {
            let page = PageController()
            page.dataExchange = dataExchange
            page.page = index
            page.book = book
            self.pages.append(page)
        }
        self.jumpToPage(page: UserDefaults.currentPage)
    }
```

Comment: where are you setting the page curl effect? as the delegate func needs this in order to work

Comment: pageviewcontrollers default behaviour is page curl